# Identify Sitecore User by Id

Tags: sitecore

Is there a unique value for sitecore users rather than username and email address, I am trying to find an Id for the user using sitecore API but I can't find any?

Answer (score 6):

Sitecore security uses the standard ASP.NET Membership provider under the hood. So you can get the Sitecore user, and then use the username to get the `MembershipUser`. The `MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey` is the Guid from the `aspnet_User` and `aspnet_Membership` tables.

```
var user = Sitecore.Context.User;
var membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(user.Name);
var userId = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
```